# Validate Checkbox and Link to New Page(s)

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I am trying to make a form that validates a checkbox. I the idea is that you have to check the box and then hit submit before moving on to a new page. So I a checkbox, and I have a function to check it, but I can't seem to get it to load the pages. I have the two pages saved here locally and they are correct, so it must be a problem with the validation function. Any help is appreciated!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>AcceptTerms</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Before proceeduing you must agree to our terms and conditions.</h1>
 <br>
 <h3>Do you accept our terms?</h3>
 <form> 
 <p><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="Yes, I accept" />Yes, I accept</p>
 <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="confirmTerms()">
 </form>    
 <br> 
 <button onclick="openDecline()">Decline Terms</button>
 <script>
 function openDecline()
 {
 window.open("declinepage.html");
 }
 </script>   
 <br>    

 <script type="text/javascript">
 function confirmTerms() {
 if (document.forms[0].checkbox.checked==false { 
 alert("You did not select a box.");
 return false
 }
 if (document.forms[0].checkbox.checked) {
 window.location.href = "acceptpage.html";
 }
 if (document.forms[0].checkbox.checked=false) {
 window.location.href = "declinepage.html";
 }
 </script>
 </body>    
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to your script.. 
I think this is what you need
and set Id for your check box

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>AcceptTerms</title>
 </head>
<body>
     <h1>Before proceeduing you must agree to our terms and conditions.</h1>

    <br>
     <h3>Do you accept our terms?</h3>

    <form>
        <p><input type="checkbox" id="check1" value="Yes, I accept" />Yes, I accept</p>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="confirmTerms()"/>
    </form>
    <br>
    <button onclick="openDecline()">Decline Terms</button>
        <script>
    function openDecline() {
        window.open("declinepage.html");
    }

    function confirmTerms() {  
        if (!(document.getElementById("check1").checked)) {
            alert("You did not select a box.");
            return false;
        }
        else{
            window.location.href = "acceptpage.html";
        }    
    }
    function openDecline(){
        if(!(document.getElementById("check1").checked)) {
            window.location.href = "declinepage.html";
        }
    }
        </script>
</body>    
 </html>
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EQa82/)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thanks for the help!

I would like to know where I went wrong here. It seems like all you did was add the getElementById method to get the information on the checkbox. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>AcceptTerms</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Before proceeduing you must agree to our terms and conditions.</h1>
 <br>
 <h3>Do you accept our terms?</h3>

 <form> 
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="Yes, I accept" />Yes, I accept</p>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="confirmTerms()">
 </form>  

 <br> 
 <button onclick="openDecline()">Decline Terms</button>
 <script>
  function openDecline()
  {
   window.open("www.facebook.com");
  }
 </script>   
 <br>    

 <script type="text/javascript">
 function confirmTerms() {

 if (document.forms[0].checkbox.checked==false) { 
 document.write("Not Checked");
 alert("You did not select a box.");
 return false;
 }

 if(document.forms[0].checkbox.checked) {
 document.write("Checked"); 
 window.location.href = "www.google.com";
 }

 }
 </script>
 </body>    
 </html>
```